# Inserting and selecting row Id in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a stored procedure, where I am inserting a row than selecting the Id of that row.

```
insert into tTest 
  (  loca
    ,name
  ) values (
    @loc
    ,@name
  );

select id from tTest where name=@name;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to combine this into one statement. Where I can select the Id of the new row as well as insert the row same time. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: If `name` is not unique, you know the current approach could return multiple rows, right? Typically you want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of querying the table, or using the `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting is absolutely bizarre to me, but try:

```
insert into tTest 
  (  loca
    ,name
  )
OUTPUT inserted.id
  values (
    @loc
    ,@name
  );
```

If you need to use the value later, you can drop your requirement of "one statement" because you'll need to either:

**Use SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

```
DECLARE @id INT;

insert into tTest 
  (  loca
    ,name
  )
  values (
    @loc
    ,@name
  );

SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

**Go overkill and use a table variable**

```
DECLARE @idTable TABLE(ID INT);

insert into tTest 
  (  loca
    ,name
  )
OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @idTable
  values (
    @loc
    ,@name
  );

-- reference @idTable later
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I use the inserted.id in my code later? Do I just use inserted.id or need to set it up with some variable?

Comment: I need to use id later to add this added row id into another table.

Comment: @J.Davidson I understand that, but your question explicitly states `in one statement`. Is that really a requirement? If not, can you please remove it from the question?

Comment: I am trying to make one statement out of one. So it is less code.

Comment: @J.Davidson well, you can't, so here are your next best options. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Look into SQL Servers `OUTPUT` clause: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx